# MapKit (macOS/iOS): MKPolyline subclass crashes upon super.init(coordinates:count:)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I want to create a subclass of `MKPolyline` so I can attach parameters like colors for the renderer. I don't think I'm doing anything fancy, but the app crashes as soon as I call `super.init(coordinates:count:)`:

```swift
public class SubroutePolyline: MKPolyline {
    /// The route of which this is a segment
    let route: APIRoute

    public init(route: APIRoute, serial sn: Int) {
        // multiPolyCoordsByRoute vends the coordinates of a route's multi-polyline
        // as [[CLLocationCoordinate 2D]].
        guard let coords = routeCoordinator.multiPolyCoordsByRoute[route.route_id],
              (0..<coords.count).contains(sn) else {
            preconditionFailure()
        }

        let theseCoordinates = coords[sn]
        self.route = route
        super.init(coordinates: theseCoordinates      ,
                   count      : theseCoordinates.count)  // [1]
    }
    ...
}
```

This class is meant to be a dropin replacement for a `MKMultiPolyline` subclass that iterated un-subclassed `MKPolyline` instances. So this initializer was the inner loop for the multi-polyline. All the data looks to be as expected. lldb reports the data types, content, and values as I expect them.

But when I step into the init on the last line ([1]), the runtime raises an exception:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UCMaps.SubroutePolyline polylineWithCoordinates:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b4400187540'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 8 (359DC264-1E1E-4BCB-A0AA-45D55389B2BC) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
```

The stack trace includes `___forwarding___` and `+[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:]`, so the message about an unrecognized selector accurately reflects what the runtime thinks is happening.

The obvious ways to distract the compiler away from a possible bug didn't work. `MKPolyline` has no subclassing notes. Writing this question out didn't work any rubber-duck debugging magic.

I'm sure I'm missing something foolishly obvious. What?

Comment: Don't subclass. Wrap. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70967

Comment: @Fritz Anderson - The link provided by matt looks like the correct way to go but I think your exception/error message is related to the MKPolyLine init. The docs indicate that you should pass an `UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>` so maybe something like `&theseCoordinates`.

Comment: @Magnas — You are entirely correct if I were using a compiler earlier than Swift 5. The migrator enforces the use of Swift-style parameters. Allocating and initializing (or casting) C-style memory structures is no longer necessary.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry about that.

Comment: @Matt — Quinn is a god, and I’m loath to question him. However: When `MKMapViewDelegate.mapView(_:rendererFor:)` is called, and you have more than one bus route, how do you know what color to apply to the renderer? `MKMultiPolyline` lets you subclass it to attach a reference to your Route object. If it’s a matter of convenience inits… `MKMultiPolyline` has a designated initializer, but `MKPolyline` hierarchy has no public designated initializer. Hard to believe `MKPL` is designed to force you to fly blind. (I have a valid reason to prefer `MKPL` over `MKMPL`.) On to DTS…

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer, once I assimilated @matt's advice:

I wanted to draw a series of polylines because my source for them doesn't put them in order (not every poly begins at the endpoint of the one before). It's difficult to be certain but the expectations seemed to be:

- **Provider**: they're just a bunch of shapes, draw them individually, never mind continuity, and it'll look right.
- **MapKit** seems to be particular about the ordering of multi-polylines. Rather than rely on `MKMultiPolyline`, I wanted to keep the constituent polys and render them individually, as I suppose is the provider's strategy.

That's why I wanted a series of `MKPolyline`s, each tagged for render metadata with the Route, just as I'd done with my subclass of `MKMultiPolyline`. `MKPolyline` can't be subclassed.

What I missed: `MKMultiPolyline` doesn't have to have more than one polyline in it. Just wrap each polyline you want to render in a `MKMultiPolyline`, and MapKit will render them piecewise.

---

I could be very wrong. Maybe I've just unmasked deeper layers of bugs. But for what it's worth, here's how you attach metadata when all you want is to draw a single polyline.